# Flot Categories Plugin Ordering Incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Thanks in advance for your time.

I have the following code for a Flot Chart

```
 <script src="js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script> 
 <script src="js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js"></script> 
 <script src="js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script> 
 <script src="js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script> 

 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){                  

  $(function() {

var data = [{
    "label": "Commission",
    "color": "#1ab394",
    "data": [["Oct", ],["Nov", ],["Dec", ],["Jan", ],["Feb", ],["Mar", ],["Apr", ],["May", 14],["Jun", 0],["Jul", 5],["Aug", 12],["Sep", 7]]
}, {
    "label": "EPL",
    "color": "#1C84C6",
     "data": [["Oct", 0],["Nov", 0],["Dec", 0],["Jan", 0],["Feb", 0],["Mar", 0],["Apr", 0],["May", 1.75],["Jun", 0.00],["Jul", 0.17],["Aug", 0.39],["Sep", 0.35]]
}];

var options = {
               series: {
                    lines: {
                            show: false,
                            fill: true
                        },
                        splines: {
                            show: true,
                            tension: 0.4,
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            fill: 0.4
                        },
                        points: {
                            radius: 0,
                            show: true
                        },
                        shadowSize: 2
                },
                grid: {
                    borderColor: '#eee',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverable: true,
                    backgroundColor: '#fff'
                },
                tooltip: true,
                tooltipOpts: {
                    content: function (label, x, y) { return x + ' : ' + y; }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    tickColor: '#eee',
                    mode: 'categories'
                },
                yaxis: {
                    tickColor: '#eee'
                },
                shadowSize: 0
            };

    var chart = $('.dashchart');
    if(chart.length)
       $.plot(chart, data, options);

  });

 })(window, document, window.jQuery);
  </script>
```

The docs state...

*By default, the labels are ordered as they are met in the data series.
If you need a different ordering, you can specify "categories" on the
axis options and list the categories there:*

https://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/jquery.flot.categories.js?r=341

However the x axis ordering is not the same as the data series, as seen in the screenshot below

Any idea why this may be.

[image: Flot chart with wrong x-axis order]

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Hope it helps someone some day

Seems Flot doesnt like empty values in the data series

```
 "data": [["Oct", ],["Nov", ],["Dec", ],["Jan", ],["Feb", ],["Mar", ],["Apr", ],["May", 14],["Jun", 0],["Jul", 5],["Aug", 12],["Sep", 7]]
```

changed to this and it works fine

```
 "data": [["Oct", 0],["Nov", 0],["Dec", 0],["Jan", 0],["Feb", 0],["Mar", ]0,["Apr", 0],["May", 14],["Jun", 0],["Jul", 5],["Aug", 12],["Sep", 7]]
```